Turntable for tanks
I am working on a project for an assemblable turntable that is meant to incur heavy weights.
Would it be possible to transfer the tank's momentum into torque for a turntable or use the tank's weight to generate torque?
(This is for a main battle tank with a mass of 90 tons.)

Run one of the tanks tracks onto the edge of the turntable then it will likely rotate.

I don't think so, generating torque means being off-center.  The motor to spin a turntable is a relatively small cost of the whole thing, you'd spend more trying to get "free" energy somehow.  You should start with Train turntables, relatively simple, in use for 150+ years, well above your weight spec.

Given that most tanks can already rotate in place under their own power, I'm having a hard time visualizing a use case for such a turntable. Also, does "assemblable" imply that it is in some sense portable? Please spell out your requirements in greater detail.
